# Create a Spring bean using arguments from another bean

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I have the following need and I want to know if can be accomplished using Spring.

I have a generic bean been used by other beans.

```
<bean id="genericCommand" class="myCommand" abstract="true">
    <property name="command" value="start service #{#this.serviceName}" />
</bean>
```

This is a specific bean using the generic bean

```
<bean id="someTasks" class="myTask">
    <property name="commands">
        <array>
            <bean parent="genericCommand">
                <property name="serviceName" value="server1" />
            </bean>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
```

It is possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible but you need to use `<list>` instead of `<array>`

```
    <list>
       <ref bean="googleGeocodingService"/>
    </list>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I think that you did not understand my question. I need to pass the service name as an argument.